# How do I match pattern and delete the whole line from multiple lines string

Tags: string, perl

I have this multiple lines string

```
IP 5002

<IP 5002
<

abcbbdbdbd
abcbbdbdbd
abcbbdbdbd
abcbbdbdbd
;
```

Im trying to match "<IP" and then subsequently delete the whole line so it would look like this

```
IP 5002

<

abcbbdbdbd
abcbbdbdbd
abcbbdbdbd
abcbbdbdbd
;
```

Code that I have only delete the <IP but not the whole line :

```
my $str = "sdasdasd
<IP 5002
<

dadas
dasdasd
dasdsada

";

$str =~ s/<IP.*//; 

print "\n" . $str . "\n";
```

Can anyone help, search result mostly involves deleting line by not reading it from a FILE and writing to a new file. Im trying to do it from a string.

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can delete the newline character:

```
$str =~ s/<IP.*\n//;
```

If you want to avoid greedy match:

```
$str =~ s/<IP.*?\n//;
```

Comment: If we are mentioning greediness (and why not) then I'd also state that `.` doesn't match the newline without the modifier `/s` (without which greediness doesn't matter here).